# Replace parameter name from query string using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Input Url

```
https://www.example.com/page/?source=something
```

Desire Output

```
https://www.example.com/page/?campaign=something
```

I've tried this but not working

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)source($|)
RewriteRule ^page/$ $1?campaign=$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

It is also adding the source= again in the URL

Comment: Can there be more query parameter other than `source` ?

Answer (score 2):

You must capture the source parameter first by enclosing the value in parenthesis

```
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING}& &source=(.*?)&
```

Now you can use the captured value with `%1`, see [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> TestString is a string which can contain the following expanded constructs in addition to plain text:
> ...
>
> - RewriteCond backreferences: These are backreferences of the form **%N** (0 <= N <= 9). **%1** to **%9** provide access to the grouped parts (again, in parentheses) of the pattern, from the last matched RewriteCond in the current set of conditions. %0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

```
RewriteRule ^page/$ $0?campaign=%1 [L,R]
```

Again see the manual [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> In addition to plain text, the Substitution string can include
>
> - back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern
> - back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern
> - server-variables as in rule condition test-strings (%{VARNAME})
> - mapping-function calls (${mapname:key|default})

And you must not use the flag [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), because this adds any new query strings instead of replacing the existing one

> Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

---

Unrelated, but *never* test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Comment: Thanks for replying but now I'm getting this as output https://www.example.org/page/?campaign=

Comment: It worked. Apparently there was some ampersands with the syntax, maybe typos, I removed them and it started working